# Java selectable JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have made a GUI with a gallery panel which shows images held in JLabels. I need to make JLabel highlightable and then remove it if the user clicks remove. Is there a way or should I change my approach?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class GalleryPanel extends JPanel 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int currentImage;
    private JLabel[] images;
    private final int MAX_IMAGES = 12;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JList<JLabel> imageGallery;
    private DefaultListModel<JLabel> listModel;
    private JPanel imageHolder;

public void init()
{   
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    imageHolder = new JPanel();
    imageHolder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(imageHolder, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    imageHolder.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());

    images = new JLabel[MAX_IMAGES];

    listModel = new DefaultListModel<JLabel>();
    listModel.addElement(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Untitled.png")));


    imageGallery = new JList<JLabel>(listModel);
    imageGallery.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    imageGallery.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    imageGallery.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    imageGallery.setFixedCellHeight(50);
    imageGallery.setFixedCellWidth(100);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageHolder);
    scrollPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


public void addImageToGallery(File file)
{
    if ( currentImage <= images.length - 1)
    {   
        BufferedImage bufImage = null;

        try
        {
            bufImage = ImageIO.read(file);  //tries to load the image
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to load file " + file.toString());
        }

        Image resizedImage = bufImage.getScaledInstance(bufImage.getWidth()/5, bufImage.getHeight()/5, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);

        images[currentImage] = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        //images[currentImage].setSize(resized);
        //images[currentImage
        images[currentImage].setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY,5), file.toString()));


        imageHolder.add(images[currentImage]);

        revalidate();
        repaint();


        currentImage++;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("The gallery is full");
    }
}


public final int getMaxImages()
{
    return MAX_IMAGES;
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
{
    return new Dimension(300, 700);
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: i know how to add a mouse listener and these borders are doing the work that i need

Comment: Okay, having scrolled a little through your code, you shouldn't be add a `JLabel` to a `ListModel`, you should never store components in data models.  Instead, store the image.  The default `ListCellRenderer` is based on a `JLabel`, if you store `ImageIcon` in the `ListModel`, `JList` will render the icon itself

Comment: Take a closer look at [How to use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), in particular the sections on [Selecting items in a List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection) and [Adding items to and removing items from a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable). You may also want to have a look at [How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more background information

Comment: Just point me to the right approach about making the image in the gallery highligthable and then make it able to be removed without having any gaps in the component

Comment: You should also look at [Making a custom component focusable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#focusable) and [`JComponent:setFocusable(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable(boolean)).  Without it, you might find it harder to "focus" on a `JLabel` to remove it.

Comment: Haven't you been asking about this same program in multiple posts over the last several days. This seems more of a "homework by committee" approach rather than a "I'm going to do most of this myself approach.

Comment: I've implemented everything on my own. I thought this site was about helping.

Comment: No, you thought wrong. This is most definitely not a help site, but rather a question and answer site, and in this situation the quality of the question is actually often more important than that of the answers. Please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see what this site is about and how to use it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And this is where we get to really screw with them ... I'm not evil or anything :D

Comment: That is why a guy from my country is ranked second with 700K reputation because he guides people and helps them.

Comment: @RadoslavTodorov There is a difference between mentoring and answering questions. With respect, had I not provided at least two core answers to your (and other related questions), you'd not be where you are right now.  We are attempting to guide you, to make you a better developer, by getting you to seek as many of the answers as you can by yourself, by using the resources around you.  The first resource should be the tutorials and searching other similar questions, not asking questions on StackOverflow. I would say you "colleague" with 700K rep has simply been around longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you first of call should be the tutorals

- [How to use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [Selecting items in a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection)
- [Adding items to and removing items from a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable)

Which will give you the basic information you need to proceeded.

Based on your available code, you should not be adding a `JLabel` to the `ListModel`, you should never add components to data models, as more often than not, Swing components have there own concept of how they will render them.

In your case, you're actually lucky, as the default `ListCellRenderer` is based on a `JLabel` and will render `Icon`'s automatically, for example

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
                model.addElement(new ImageIcon("mt01.jpg"));
                model.addElement(new ImageIcon("mt02.jpg"));
                model.addElement(new ImageIcon("mt03.jpg"));

                JList list = new JList(model);
                list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
                list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                            System.out.println(list.getSelectedIndex());
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: but then i won't be able to surround the image with a border

Comment: @RadoslavTodorov Run the example, `JList` will do this for you automatically

Comment: I wrote my custom ListCellRenderer. Is there a way to get the ImageIcon's name inside the ListCellRenderer so that I could set it as the title in a TitledBorder? The Images will be added and removed.

Comment: Create a wrapper class which wraps the icon and name, put that in the ListModel

Comment: This is my only way to communicate now since you were so generous to get me banned :D. I am also having trouble with making the cell width just enough to fit the image icon. I tried setFixedCellWidth() but it had no effect. It has a gap on the right side. I suppose it has something to do with the JList's size.

Comment: Take a look at [`JList#getPrototypeCellValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getPrototypeCellValue()).  `fixedCellWidth` should work, but then it comes down to what layout manager you're using

Comment: I set the filename as the ImageIcon description and i managed to display the title. I am using a boxlayout manager

Comment: Not particularly experienced with `BoxLayout`, probably would prefer a `GridBagLayout` myself